# Phase and group velocities in QFT / Quantum Optics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, phase-velocity

How does one define phase and group velocities in QFT? More precisely, are they referring to the *mode structure* of the field or do they characterize excitations?

The question is motivated by question [Speed of photon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720601/247642), which asks for a phase and group velocities of a single photon. Thus, if we take the definitions from classical electrodynamics,
$$
v_{ph}=\frac{\omega}{k},\textrm{ }v_g=\frac{d\omega(k)}{dk}|_{k=k_0},
$$
then the two velocities characterize the mode structure of the field (plane waves in free space, but something else in a  confined geometry), rather then actual excitation, and we could say that they are the same for a single photon, or any more complex state.

On the other hand, a single-photon state $a_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}^\dagger |0\rangle$ is not really any close to a plane wave (unlike a coherent state), so speaking about its phase and group velocities is a kind of meaningless (although it could be meaningful for a coherent state).

To restate the question:

- Are there standard generalizations for phase and group velocities in QFT or Quantum Optics?
- If not, what would be a meaningful way to extend these definitions to the quantum case?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143696/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254200/2451

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/384276/247642

Answer (score 1):

A general single-photon state can be represented as
$$ |\psi_1\rangle = \int \hat{a}_s^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k}) \psi_s(\mathbf{k})\ \frac{\text{d}^3 k}{(2\pi)^3} |\text{vac}\rangle , $$
where $\psi_s(\mathbf{k})$ is a normalized angular spectrum (or Fourier domain wave function), and $|\text{vac}\rangle$ is the vacuum state. As a result, the phase velocity and group velocity are governed by the properties of state are governed by $\psi_s(\mathbf{k})$, very similar to the way the angular spectrum  determines these properties for a classical field.